# print() with flush=True is not fully clearing print output when subsequent output is a shorter length

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

If you run this code for a few iterations you will see that a print message followed by a shorter print message will result in some part of the longer message being left in the output of the shorter message.

```py
import random
import time

names = ['Mike', 'Alexander', 'Tom', 'Johnny']
numbers = list(range(0, 10))
while True:
    name = random.choice(names)
    number = random.choice(numbers)
    print('\rName: {} - Number: {}'.format(name, number), end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

**EDIT**

I changed the code to this which resolved the problem:

```py
import random
import time

names = ['Mike', 'Alexander', 'Tom', 'Johnny']
numbers = list(range(0, 10))
msg_len = 0
while True:
    name = random.choice(names)
    number = random.choice(numbers)
    msg = '\rName: {} - Number: {}'.format(name, number)
    buffer = msg_len - len(msg)
    buffer = buffer if buffer > 0 else 0
    print(msg, end=' '*buffer, flush=True)
    msg_len = len(msg)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been left in the output, per se.  You're reprinting on the same line, but this does *not* include an implicit cleaning of the previous output.  If you want to erase that, you need to do so actively, such as overwriting the previous line length with blanks.